# Keep updated text next to image

Tags: html, css, image, user-experience

I have text that is placed next to an image. I am using AngularJS so that text dynamically changes. I want that text to fit next to that image no matter what and not spill over.

CSS:

```
.album-art{
    float: left;
    height: 115px;
    width: 115px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.player{
    background-color: black;
}

.now-playing-text {
    color: white;
    float:left;
}

.gotham-bold-text {
    font-family: gotham-bold;
}

.gotham-book-text {
    font-family: gotham-book;
}

.playing-text {
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
   <ion-view title="Now Playing">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-content class="player">
    <div class="now-playing">
        <canvas class="visualizer"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="container-text">
    <div class="playing-text"><img class="album-art" src="{{art}}"><h1 class="now-playing-text"><div class="gotham-bold-text">{{title}}</div></h1></div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Try and see if text-align:justify; works.

Comment: I dont know where it is "spilling over" to . But you should maybe look into `word-wrap`